# Транслитерация столбца таблицы

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Подскажите, имеется ли функция в Питон, чтобы перевести кириллицу в латиницу в одном столбце Эксель файла?
Вполне себе представляю код для обработки текстового файла, но в таблице не могу сделать...

```
dic = {
    'а': 'a',
    'б': 'b',
    'в': 'v',
    'г': 'g',
    'д': 'd',
    'е': 'e',
    'ё': 'yo',
    'ж': 'zh',
    'з': 'z',
    'и': 'i',
    'й': 'y',
    'к': 'k',
    'л': 'l',
    'м': 'm',
    'н': 'n',
    'о': 'o',
    'п': 'p',
    'р': 'r',
    'с': 's',
    'т': 't',
    'у': 'u',
    'ф': 'f',
    'х': 'h',
    'ц': 'ts',
    'ч': 'ch',
    'ш': 'sh',
    'щ': 'shch',
    'ъ': 'y',
    'ы': 'y',
    'ь': "'",
    'э': 'e',
    'ю': 'yu',
    'я': 'ya',

    'А': 'A',
    'Б': 'B',
    'В': 'V',
    'Г': 'G',
    'Д': 'D',
    'Е': 'E',
    'Ё': 'Yo',
    'Ж': 'Zh',
    'З': 'Z',
    'И': 'I',
    'Й': 'Y',
    'К': 'K',
    'Л': 'L',
    'М': 'M',
    'Н': 'N',
    'О': 'O',
    'П': 'P',
    'Р': 'R',
    'С': 'S',
    'Т': 'T',
    'У': 'U',
    'Ф': 'F',
    'Х': 'H',
    'Ц': 'Ts',
    'Ч': 'Ch',
    'Ш': 'Sh',
    'Щ': 'Shch',
    'Ъ': 'Y',
    'Ы': 'Y',
    'Ь': "'",
    'Э': 'E',
    'Ю': 'Yu',
    'Я': 'Ya', }
with open('200_.txt', encoding='ibm866') as fh:
    data = fh.read()
result = ''
for i in data:
    if i in dic:
        result += dic[i]
    else:
        result += i
print(result)
```

Comment: давайте код для текстового файла и тестовый вариант таблицы. прикрутим

Comment: dic = { здесь русские буквы и английские, я их удалил так как не влезли в комментарий 
    }
with open('200_.txt', encoding='ibm866') as fh:
    data = fh.read()
result = ''
for i in data:
    if i in dic:
        result += dic[i]
    else:
        result += i
print(result)

Comment: Код добавьте в сам вопрос (нажмите [edit] под ним, чтобы отредактировать). Комментарии не предназначены для размещения блоков кода.

Comment: @splash58 добавил

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае можно преобразовывать проще, пользуясь методом translate

```
t = str.maketrans(dic)
print('Привет, Jho'.translate(t)) 

# Privet, Jho
```

---

им же можно воспользоваться и в pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['Привет, Jho', 'другая тестовая строка']})
print(df.c.str.translate(t))

0                 Privet, Jho
1    drugaya testovaya stroka
Name: c, dtype: object
```